# Is there a lower bound on the rate of growth of distinct algorithms (vs. description size) in a Turing-complete system?

Tags: computability, information-theory, turing-machines, kolmogorov-complexity

...where a "distinct algorithm" is approximately defined as an algorithm that returns a value distinct from all others thus far.

I would think not, because you can always construct some pathological language that requires ever-increasing arbitrary strings of inputs to properly encode a useful command, and otherwise treats it all as a NOOP/ignores it.

On the other hand, I know there's that great property to K-complexity which provides a firm constant as an upper bound for how much longer the same algorithm can be when compared between any two languages.

These two outlooks are in conflict, so I know I'm overlooking something here. What is it?

Comment: "On the other hand, I know there's that great property to K-complexity which provides a firm constant as an upper bound for how much longer the same algorithm can be when compared between any two languages." I don't understand this - can you elaborate?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Invariance_theorem, and that as I understand it, it means any two Turing-complete languages cannot differ my more than a constant for the same algorithm. In fact, that makes it sound like the difference in K-complexity between any two languages should be effectively nil in the limit.